# C++ Plugin can't delay load a dll

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine, visual-c++

I am bridging Nvidia Blast to Unity, and I am running into the following error when PhysX is trying to delay load `PhysX3CommonDEBUG_x64.dll`:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFDD7743FB8 (KernelBase.dll) in Unity.exe: 
0xC06D007E: Module not found (parameters: 0x00000000005FC5B0).`
```

I am able to run this bridging program fine as a standalone console application (after changing the project type), but running the PhysX initialization inside of Unity causes the crash (here's Unity's stacktrace):

```
0x00007FFF4F543FB8 (KERNELBASE) RaiseException
0x00007FFEF0840835 (PhysX3DEBUG_x64) [f:\dd\vctools\delayimp\delayhlp.cpp:323] __delayLoadHelper2 
0x00007FFEF0669011 (PhysX3DEBUG_x64) _tailMerge_physx3commondebug_x64_dll
0x00007FFEF051CDA4 (PhysX3DEBUG_x64) [c:\users\jesse\documents\github\physx-3.4\physx_3.4\source\physx\src\npfactory.cpp:67] physx::NpFactory::NpFactory
0x00007FFEF051D6ED (PhysX3DEBUG_x64) [c:\users\jesse\documents\github\physx-3.4\physx_3.4\source\physx\src\npfactory.cpp:122] physx::NpFactory::createInstance
0x00007FFEF0545721 (PhysX3DEBUG_x64) [c:\users\jesse\documents\github\physx-3.4\physx_3.4\source\physx\src\npphysics.cpp:269] physx::NpPhysics::createInstance
0x00007FFEF0544DAA (PhysX3DEBUG_x64) [c:\users\jesse\documents\github\physx-3.4\physx_3.4\source\physx\src\npphysics.cpp:831] PxCreateBasePhysics
0x00007FFF18D37FA3 (Fractre) [c:\users\jesse\documents\github\blast\compiler\fractre\fractre.cpp:60] Initialize
```

I can definetely confirm that `PhysX3CommonDEBUG_x64.dll` and all other dlls are present in plugin directory (like Unity expects) and there were complaints when they were missing but now they've been addressed.

I have also ran [Window's System File Checker](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/929833/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system) and it found no integrity issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> confirm that PhysX3CommonDEBUG_x64.dll and all other dlls are present in plugin directory (like Unity expects)

It doesn’t matter what Unity expects. When you use `/DELAYLOAD` linker flag to link with a native DLL, it’s not Unity who’s loading that DLL — Windows does.

[Here’s a documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx) about DLL search order. There’s [a special API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686203(v=vs.85).aspx) you can call to specify custom DLL location but handle with care, could be security consequences if someone will trick your app to load a hacked version of that DLL instead of the correct one.

Couple other notes. Ensure you’re using correct architecture, i.e. both Unity project and PhysX are 64 bit. Also ensure any DLLs PhysX3CommonDEBUG depends on are also available for LoadLibrary.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I can't believe I fixed it just then. I went down literally dozens paths trying to figure it out, but I was very, very silly and didn't believe that it simply could not find the dll. In Process Monitor I can see when Unity is opened it finds the dll, but when I load my plugin it looks in all the places only Windows would look for it, and since Unity is the current process it does look in Unity's program directory, and not my Unity project directory. I've solved it temporarily by simply copying PhysX3Common into Unity's applciation folder.

Comment: @AquaGeneral IMO one good non-temporarily solution is load your DLLs manually, with LoadLibrary API passing absolute paths to them. Once loaded, windows will no longer search these directories, it’ll use whatever DLL is already loaded. If the DLL has custom dependencies, you’ll have to manually load them first. But in the end LoadLibrary is more reliable than SetDllDirectory. You can do that in C# if you want: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.LoadLibrary

Comment: Good idea, I'll look into that later.

Answer (score 0):

Here's 3 solutions that will work (as of PhysX 4.1):

- Build PhysX statically
- Remove the DELAYLOAD/ from their CMake.
- Load the libraries that need to be delay loaded yourself. Just import kernel32 LoadLibrary (or dlopen/close on unix) and call it on those few libraries before calling any functions that would have had it loaded.